# A function of the characters of a representation that determine how many orbits there are

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, group-actions, characters

Let $G$ be a finite (even cyclic group generated by $g$) and $X$ be a set on which it acts and considering the permutation representation induced by this, let $\chi_i$ be the set of characters. Then, the number of fixed points for instance is given by $|G|^{-1}(\sum_i \chi(g)$) and similarly, Burnside's lemma will give you a formula for the number of orbits.

My question is: is there an auxiliary representation we can construct such that the character of this rep evaluated at a generator (or a linear combination over evaluations at various elements) is one (or a constant that only depends on the group) exactly when the original representation has a fixed point and is 0 otherwise?

Comment: What kind of formula are you looking for? You already have a formula for the number of fixed points, so you can already check whether or not there are fixed points at all.

Comment: Something that involves field operations but now that I think about it I could use some sort of finite fourier expansion. Let me think about it.

Comment: I don't think using an exponential sum works in my context. :(

Comment: What do you mean the "set" of characters? There's one permutation rep, so there's only one character. Or do you mean all the irreducible characters corresponding to how the permutation rep decomposes into irreps, counted with multiplicitiy? Second, your exponential formula seems completely meaningless and irrelevant to me, and in particular it does not evaluate to just $0$ or $1$ like you want. Third, echoing Joppy's comment, what's wrong with simply using $\sum_g \chi(g)$ to count the number of fixed points?

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully it makes more sense now (and is a little different). I mean the irreducible characters. I don't want the number of fixed points, I just want to know if there are any.

Comment: But obviously you can know if there are any by seeing if the number is zero or not zero. Also the title seems to ask a different question.

Comment: Fixed the title. The problem is I want a new rep that encodes this data.

Comment: I am confused. It seems to me the property you are looking is satisfied by the permutation character you started with.

Comment: By non zero I meant to say some constant independent of the number of the fixed points.